Proving identities for $\cos(x\sin\theta)$ and $\sin(x\sin\theta)$ involving Bessel functions.
I'm working on this exercise about Bessel functions:

Suppose $x>0$ and $\theta\in\mathbb{R}$. Show that
$$\cos(x\sin\theta) = J_0(x)+2\sum_{n=1}^{+\infty}J_{2n}(x)\cos(2n\theta)$$
$$\sin(x\sin\theta) = 2\sum_{n=1}^{+\infty}J_{2n-1}(x)\sin((2n-1)\theta)$$

The exercise comes from a section about the generatig function of Bessel function of integral order so probabily I should use those results:
$$e^{\frac{x}{2}(t-\frac{1}{t})}=\sum_{n=-\infty}^{+\infty} J_n(x)t^n \;\;\text{ where }\;\;t\in\mathbb{C}-\{0\} \;,\;x>0$$
$$J_n(x)=\frac{1}{\pi}\int_0^{\pi}\cos(x\sin\theta -n\theta)d\theta \;\;\text{ where }\;\;n\in\mathbb{Z} \;,\;x>0$$
I've already prove the first part but I don't know how to start with $\sin(x\cos\theta)$. I've tried to use some trig identities to find an expression in term of cosine and even tried to connect both statements via $e^{ix\sin\theta}=\cos(x\sin\theta)+i\sin(x\sin\theta)$ but without any success.
Can you please give me an hint?

How did you prove the first part? You can substitute $t=e^{i\theta}$, separate the sum over positive/negative integers, and take the real/imaginary parts to get the identities.

@TymaGaidash For the first part I used the expression of $J_n(x)$ as integral with $n=0$. Thanks for your hint.

As for the cosine,
$$\begin{aligned}
\color{green}{\cos(x\sin\theta)}&=\dfrac{e^{ix\sin\theta}+e^{-ix\sin\theta}}{2}\\
&=\dfrac{e^{\frac{x}{2}(e^{i\theta}-e^{-i\theta})}+e^{-\frac{x}{2}(e^{i\theta}-e^{-i\theta})}}{2}\\
&=\dfrac{1}{2}\sum_{n\in\mathbf Z}\{J_n(x)e^{in\theta}+(-1)^nJ_n(x)e^{in\theta}\}\\
&=\sum_{n\in\mathbf Z}J_{2n}(x)e^{i2n\theta}\\
&=J_0(x)+\sum_{n\in\mathbf Z_{>1}}J_{2n}(x)e^{i2n\theta}+\sum_{n\in\mathbf Z_{>1}}J_{-2n}(x)e^{-i2n\theta}\\
&=J_0(x)+\sum_{n\in\mathbf Z_{>1}}J_{2n}(x)e^{i2n\theta}+\sum_{n\in\mathbf Z_{>1}}(-1)^{2n}J_{2n}(x)e^{-i2n\theta}\\
&\color{green}{=J_0(x)+2\sum_{n\in\mathbf Z_{>1}}J_{2n}(x)\cos(2n\theta)}
\end{aligned}$$
Similarly for the sine,
$$\begin{aligned}
\color{purple}{\sin(x\sin\theta)}&=\dfrac{e^{ix\sin\theta}-e^{-ix\sin\theta}}{2i}\\
&=\dfrac{e^{\frac{x}{2}(e^{i\theta}-e^{-i\theta})}-e^{-\frac{x}{2}(e^{i\theta}-e^{-i\theta})}}{2i}\\
&=\dfrac{1}{2i}\sum_{n\in\mathbf Z}\{J_n(x)e^{in\theta}+(-1)^{n+1}J_n(x)e^{in\theta}\}\\
&=\dfrac{1}{i}\sum_{n\in\mathbf Z}J_{2n-1}(x)e^{i(2n-1)\theta}\\
&=\dfrac{1}{i}\sum_{n\in\mathbf Z_{>1}}J_{2n-1}(x)e^{i(2n-1)\theta}+\dfrac{1}{i}\sum_{n\in\mathbf Z_{>1}}J_{-2n+1}(x)e^{-i(2n-1)\theta}\\
&=\dfrac{1}{i}\sum_{n\in\mathbf Z_{>1}}J_{2n-1}(x)e^{i(2n-1)\theta}+\dfrac{1}{i}\sum_{n\in\mathbf Z_{>1}}(-1)^{2n-1}J_{2n-1}(x)e^{-i(2n-1)\theta}\\
&\color{purple}{=2\sum_{n\in\mathbf Z_{>1}}J_{2n-1}(x)\sin[(2n-1)\theta]}
\end{aligned}$$

You can also obtain this result if you compute the Fourier series of these two functions. In fact, the coefficient integrals turn out to be the even and odd Bessel functions.
